# Joining tables not working in the post editor page

Tags: filters, join-tables

I am developing a plug-in which stores data in a custom table and is joined onto the `wp_posts` by the post's the id. I then use the `posts_join` and `post_fields` filters to join my table and be able retrieve data from it. For example:

```
    add_filter('posts_join', 'my_join' );
    function my_join( $join ){
        global $wpdb; 
        $join .= "LEFT JOIN wp_my_table ON $wpdb->posts.ID = wp_my_table.postID "; 

        return $join;
    }
```

This works well on the front end (and even most of the admin), but when a post is being edited, the join doesn't seem to happen. For instance, in my plugin's custom metabox on the edit page, `var_dump($post)` reveals all the standard fields, but none of my plugin's.

When a post is being edited, does it skip the `posts_join`, `posts_fields` filters? Is there another hook that can be used?

---

**Update**

I have done some further tests. Let's suppose I am on;
*../post.php?post=703&action=edit*. As in my comment to Chris' response, the `the_post` hook reveals that the table has been successfully joined at that point (and the post is 703).

On the other hand there are two calls to `posts_selection` and both are for revision posts that are the children of 703. (I have attempted joining to their parent, but this does not work - even after ensuring filters are not suppressed).

I can, of course, just retrieve my data inside the metabox - but I would like to know if it would be possible to avoid having to do this. (And quite what goes on when click to edit a post :D!)

Comment: Is there any reason your not using post_meta?

Comment: Yes, the amount of data I'm storing means using a new table makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found my answer. Digging through posts.php in admin, in line 182, just before WordPress includes `./edit-form-advanced.php`, we have;

```
$post = get_post_to_edit($post_id);
```

(see, [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/post.php)). If we look up `get_post_to_edit`,  (it's buried deep, [see here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/includes/post.php), line 475), we find that this uses `get_post()` to retrieve the post. `get_post()` retrieves posts by id and does not offer any way to alter the query (and in particular join other tables.). `get_post` [lives here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/post.php) by the way, line 370).

This is the root of the problem. And as it stands, you can't return all the custom data with the post - you'll have to do it by using the id of the post and query the database again (which I know is no big deal..).

Answer (score 0):

The easy way in the admin is to do a 2nd custom query using the post_id from the post object.

```
function custom_posts_data( $posts, $query ) {
       global $wpdb;  
       if ( !count( $posts ) ) 
           return $posts;  

       while ( $posts as $post ) {        
           $query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}my_plugin_table WHERE post_id={$post->ID}";
           $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
       }
       return $posts;
   }
   add_filter( 'the_posts', 'custom_posts_data' );
```

If you need to do the full joins have a look at [scibu's sortable columns example](http://scribu.net/wordpress/sortable-taxonomy-columns.html)
or [Mitcho's orderby joins filter examples.](http://mitcho.com/blog/how-to/external-orders-in-wordpress-queries/)

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the answer. I have done some tests and $query is null at the_posts hook. Interestingly, $posts at that point is an array (of size one) which includes all the data from my table as well the standard post data. This must mean that in between 'the_posts' filter and WordPress calling my metaboxes the data is lost ($post is re-retrieved..?). Any ideas?